# Can you tell me why HTML DIV closes before PHP function execution in echo?

Tags: php, html

I am facing a strange problem.
My PHP page has following code.

```
echo "<div id='page_$i' class='layout_pages'>".eval('?>' . $layouts[$i]. '<?php ')."</div>";
```

Here $i is my iterator and $layouts is an Array which have multiple layouts fetched from database in it. Some layouts have PHP code in them. That's why I am using eval function.

Now problem is that HTML output of this code is something like that

```
<div id='page_$i' class='layout_pages'></div>
//Layout output goes here
```

Ideally layout out should be wrapped in this DIV. But Div starts and closes before layout. Can you suggest me some good solution.

**[Solved]**

Well mates, I solved this issue by making following changes in code. Rather showing all data in one echo statement. I used multiple echo commands and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

```
<div id='page_<?php echo $i; ?>' class='layout_pages' ><?php echo eval('?>' . $layouts[$i]. '<?php '); ?></div>;
```

As i dun have 100 points. So cant answer my own question. That's why i am editing my question :)

Comment: That rates as one of the most bizarre attempts to use eval that I've seen. What are you trying to achieve with it? It looks like you are trying to take a string and build a PHP script from it that outputs it without modification, and then eval that so you get the original string out again.

Comment: Actually i have some PHP code in $layouts array. Thats why i need to use this function. Well end output is simple HTML code.

Comment: If you're putting PHP code in an array and eval-ing it, You're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: well, its on an index of array. I dun think that there should be some issue with it. Its similar to a PHP variable.

Comment: It would be much better to have a function that you call with whatever `$i` is as the argument, which will return the HTML that your `eval`ed code produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rogue eval function in there is probably the culprit, I would recommend doing it like this instead:

```
echo "<div id='page_".$i."' class='layout_pages'>".$layouts[$i]."</div>";
```

Comment: ummm, but eval is required for smooth functional flow. Otherwise i will have to make lot of changes in multiple files.

Comment: I've just seen your comment on the original post, I don't use eval() very often, but from my understanding something like this should work

echo "<div id='page_".$i."' class='layout_pages'>".eval($layouts[$i])."</div>";

Comment: echo was actual culprit mate. I have edited my question. issue is resolved. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you dump $layout contents? May be there is an empty element at the begining of $layout...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<div id='page_$i' class='layout_pages'>".eval('return ('. $layouts[$i].');')."</div>";
```

Otherwise eval returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<div id='page_$i' class='layout_pages'>",eval('?>' . $layouts[$i]. '<?php '),"</div>";
```